# getting conversion error while trying to wrap 2 Polly policies

Tags: c#, timeout, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

I am trying to wrap two Polly policies and want to return `IAsyncPolicy`, but it giving error,

> convert from Polly.Retry.RetryPolicy < System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> to Polly.IAsyncPolicy

```
public static IAsyncPolicy CreateDefaultRetryPolicy()
    {
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));

        var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
                .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
                (result, timeSpan, context) =>
                {
                });

        return Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy);
    }
```

How to wrap this and return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapt your code as follows:

```
public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateDefaultRetryPolicy()
{
    var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
            .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
            .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
            (result, timeSpan, context) =>
            {
            });

    return timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);
}
```

#### Explanation

- The timeout policy is non-generic, `IAsyncPolicy`.
- The wait-and-retry policy is generic, `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`, as it handles `HttpResponseMessage` results.

To combined these in a PolicyWrap, use the `.Wrap(...)` instance-method syntax:

```
return timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);
```

As the resulting PolicyWrap handles `HttpResponseMessage`, it is also of type `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`, so the method return type changes to that.

Polly documentation covers the differences between non-generic and generic policies in the [wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Non-generic-and-generic-policies).